# Error when trying to open xml files with view-source programatically

Tags: javascript, xml, firefox

When I'd open `www.example.com/some_html.html` I'd like a small script in Tampermonkey to detect the .html, open a new tab with `view-source` appended infront of the string.

In theory, I already have working code

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         XML
// @version      0.1
// @description  Opens files, Yay!
// @include      /^.*\.xml$/
// @exclude      /^view-source:.*\.xml$/
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    window.location.replace(`view-source:${window.location.href}`)
})();
```

Sadly, when I open a sitemap for example it prints out this big error

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Location.replace: Access to 'view-source:http://drupal-blog.lndo.site/en/sitemap.xml' from script denied.
    tms_8214f41c_65d5_4e50_86b6_a5ea16f2256e$/< moz-extension://9c13b008-02bf-4abc-9c1e-f8db84075d3f/userscripts/XML.user.js?id=8214f41c-65d5-4e50-86b6-a5ea16f2256e:13
    tms_8214f41c_65d5_4e50_86b6_a5ea16f2256e$ moz-extension://9c13b008-02bf-4abc-9c1e-f8db84075d3f/userscripts/XML.user.js?id=8214f41c-65d5-4e50-86b6-a5ea16f2256e:14
    it http://drupal-blog.lndo.site/en/sitemap.xml:14
    window["__p__185308.9699366292"]/</< moz-extension://9c13b008-02bf-4abc-9c1e-f8db84075d3f/userscripts/XML.user.js?id=8214f41c-65d5-4e50-86b6-a5ea16f2256e:1
    window["__p__185308.9699366292"]/< moz-extension://9c13b008-02bf-4abc-9c1e-f8db84075d3f/userscripts/XML.user.js?id=8214f41c-65d5-4e50-86b6-a5ea16f2256e:1
    "__p__185308.9699366292" moz-extension://9c13b008-02bf-4abc-9c1e-f8db84075d3f/userscripts/XML.user.js?id=8214f41c-65d5-4e50-86b6-a5ea16f2256e:15
    it http://drupal-blog.lndo.site/en/sitemap.xml:14
    set http://drupal-blog.lndo.site/en/sitemap.xml:3
    <anonymous> moz-extension://9c13b008-02bf-4abc-9c1e-f8db84075d3f/userscripts/XML.user.js?id=8214f41c-65d5-4e50-86b6-a5ea16f2256e:1
    it http://drupal-blog.lndo.site/en/sitemap.xml:14
    t http://drupal-blog.lndo.site/en/sitemap.xml:4
    it http://drupal-blog.lndo.site/en/sitemap.xml:14
    y http://drupal-blog.lndo.site/en/sitemap.xml:6
    send http://drupal-blog.lndo.site/en/sitemap.xml:7
    V http://drupal-blog.lndo.site/en/sitemap.xml:3
    E_u http://drupal-blog.lndo.site/en/sitemap.xml:4
    E_u http://drupal-blog.lndo.site/en/sitemap.xml:4
    create eval:64
    create eval:65
    l eval:6
    it http://drupal-blog.lndo.site/en/sitemap.xml:14
    a eval:3
    r eval:4
    M http://drupal-blog.lndo.site/en/sitemap.xml:6
    M http://drupal-blog.lndo.site/en/sitemap.xml:6
    it http://drupal-blog.lndo.site/en/sitemap.xml:14
    t http://drupal-blog.lndo.site/en/sitemap.xml:4
    it http://drupal-blog.lndo.site/en/sitemap.xml:14
    y http://drupal-blog.lndo.site/en/sitemap.xml:6
    send http://drupal-blog.lndo.site/en/sitemap.xml:7
    r eval:4
    setTimeout eval:4
    t eval:7
    runListeners eval:6
    run eval:7
    TM_back eval:67
    it http://drupal-blog.lndo.site/en/sitemap.xml:14
    t http://drupal-blog.lndo.site/en/sitemap.xml:15
    TM_back eval:67
    TM_back eval:67
    TM_back eval:68
    "__c__17560039.84757176" eval:68
    it http://drupal-blog.lndo.site/en/sitemap.xml:14
    set http://drupal-blog.lndo.site/en/sitemap.xml:3
    <anonymous> eval:1
sitemap.xml line 14 > eval:13:21
```

My question now is, if this is perhaps due to a certain header that isn't or is set or because of a security rule in firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1172165):

> Linking to view-source: is only useful for browser developers. IE
> already dropped support in XP SP2, citing security concerns. We should
> probably remove it too.
>
> The view-source: protocol has caused quite a few security bugs in
> Firefox, msotly due to security checks failing to take view-source's
> specialness into account:
> https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=481342,762705,561051,645564,290982,290949,262689
>
> And the protocol continues to be a danger to the security of web sites
> with private information or CSRF tokens:
> https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=263290,624883,973837,1171853

It is a security rule in Firefox.